# ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_URL in the user request

Tags: javascript

I have an application constructed in seam and rich faces.

When I log in, I could see `ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_URL` along with other requests consuming 1-3 ms of time.

How can I avoid this? I checked it clicking F12 in IE.

I tried changing my pack.js file in the following ways:

```
document.write("<script id=__onDOMContentLoaded defer src=//:><\/script>");
```

I replaced:

```
src=//:
```

with different combinations like:

```
src='//:blank.js'
src=\"javascript:void(0)\"
src=''
src=“about:blank”
src=://0
```

but it is not completely replacing the     `://:/` in the request

Can any one please suggest how to get rid of this issue??

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess doing it this way will be more clear and easier.

**answer was updated as per the comments, thank you  Teemu & Tommi**

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('src',sourcepath);
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: `document.head` for example

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` will return you nodes collection, which have no method `.appendChild` so you should get [0] element or just use `document.head`